# Service is not able to read Shared Preference after restart

Tags: android, multithreading, service, sharedpreferences, handler

In my application, I have a Service which reads Shared Preferences after restart. But the problem is some times service is able to read correct values from shared preference and some times not.

1. When Service is killed by Android (not able to read correct values)
2. When Service is killed by user manually (Same)

In both the cases, Service is restarting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first,make sure where your save the value,did you save in the same process?secondly,make sure the value was saved before your service was killed.

Answer (score 0):

Did you restart Service like  `return START_REDELIVER_INTENT;`?

Comment: No I am not starting the service using return START_REDELIVER_INTENT I am retarting it in service's on Destroy();